# Among which "people" should we make "his deeds known"?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, king-david

Beginning of [Psalm 105](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.105.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> .הודוּ לה' קִרְאוּ בִשְׁמו. הודִיעוּ בָעַמִּים עֲלִילותָיו
>
> Give thanks to the Lord, call out in His name; make His deeds known among the peoples.

- Which people? Fellow Jews? Among non-Jews?
- Which deeds?
- Is this an obligation, or just an expression of our gratitude to God?
- Do we know of any instances where this was practiced?

Comment: Every Shabbos, every Yom Tov, every Bracha, & every time we Daven are occasions where we make His deeds known

Comment: @Lages but here it specifically says "among the peoples" which the mitzudas commentary explains to mean the nations of the world. When we are praying and saying blessings we are making his deeds known amongst our fellow Jews.

Answer (score -2):

Mitzudas commentary says it means "to the nations" (עמים), so it appears to be referring to the nations of the world.

This Psalm was composed when David was tranporting the Ark of the covenant to Jerusalem, and they were singing as they went. So taken in the context of the story, it seems that they were singing the praises of God to all the people they passed on way to Jerusalem.

A source: The intro for the Psalm 105 in the Ohel Yosef Yitzchok Tehilim says that this song was said by David as written above. And that David was recounting the Miracles that was done in Egypt.

Comment: Metzudas says עמים means עמים, interesting? 2. Are you immediately answering your own question?

Comment: You don't address questions 2-4. I don't think you can say "it was practiced before David wrote it down"

Comment: @AlBerko FYI [there is no problem answering one's own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: @AlBerko my question mostly still remains. Perhaps I'll edit my current (tentative) answer into the question.

Comment: @AlBerko if the explanation is indeed so simple, than why would the commentary bother commentating on it? Obviously there is a need to emphasize it.